# Dealing with two DateTimePicker too error prone?

Tags: c#

So often, I want the user to select a start date and a finish date. But just selecting date is not enough, we also have to alter the data.

By default, the `DateTimePicker.Value` are like

```
Value 1: 2012-01-01 10:12:09
Value 2: 2012-01-02 10:12:09
```

When the user selects two dates, it should be obvious that he meant

```
Value 1: 2012-01-01 00:00:00
Value 2: 2012-01-02 23:59:59
```

I often forget to do the non-intuitive

```
DateTime start = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
DateTime finish = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

What more effective way of dealing with this have you found?

Comment: I think your way is very effective.  With a short comment in the code it should be fine.

Comment: The only thing I don't necessarily agree with is the "should be obvious" part, and subtracting one second from the finish date.  What's wrong with data greater than or equal to the start, and less than the finish?  Then you don't lose the case where something happens in that one second.  If that's not a use case for you, then fine - this is just something that I have found to occassionally cause a hard-to-find bug.

Comment: @WonkotheSane I agree with you. Both ways are equivalent, but being consistent is the key. That is why I think there should be a settable property for DateTimePickers stating that you want the start or the end of the date. That would create a standard and, therefore, improve consistency

Comment: @Mathieu I like your idea. You could easily adjust the `StartDateTimePicker` class to include an enum that is passed into the constructor. The enum would possibly contain values for "start of the date", "end of the date", and "no adjustment". The event handler would simply do different logic based on which enum value it's configured to use.  (You'd obviously rename the class to something that represents the new functionality.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `DateTimePicker` objects lke this a lot, you could possible create two small custom classes: a `StartDateTimePicker` and an `EndDateTimePicker`.  Each class would derive from `DateTimePicker`, and would simply have a boolean and an EventHandler on the [OnValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.onvaluechanged.aspx) event.  The event would be used to adjust the value after it is set, and the boolean would be used to implement the [Balking Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balking_pattern).  Here's an example of the `StartDateTimePicker`:

```
public class StartDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    bool handling = false;

    // Note: 
    public StartDateTimePicker()
        : base()
    {
        // This could be simplified to a lambda expression
        this.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(StartDateTimePicker_ValueChanged);
    }

    void StartDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the value is being changed by this event, don't change it again
        if (handling)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            handling = true;
            // Add your DateTime adjustment logic here:
            Value = Value.Date;
        }
        finally
        {
            handling = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then simply use these in place of your normal `DateTimePicker` objects and you would not have to worry about making sure that the dates are appropriately adjusted anymore.

It would cost you the time to write the `EndDateTimePicker` class (the above is already a fully functional `StartDateTimePicker`), but it would make things easier down the road as you use these in more places.

Comment: I'd suggest combining the two into a `DateRangePicker`.